# Windows boot sequence operation

Tags: windows, bios, uefi

I am targeting at creating software for the Windows pre-boot environment but I have hard time finding conclusive information about how it operates. For background: this software will communicate with an external server in order to determine if the boot sequence should continue or not.

My current understanding is as follow
UEFI/BIOS -> **Pre-boot environment** -> Windows(after booting)

I found that the pre-boot environment operates using the so called "mini kernel". Is it true and is this mini-kernel the same Windows kernel with just limited stuff enabled?